# How to wrap bulk upsert in Mongo with Task in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I have some model

```
public partial class Option
{
  [BsonId]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Quote Quote { get; set; }
  public Contract Contract { get; set; }
}
```

Method that does bulk write

```
public Task SaveOptions(List<Option> contracts)
{
  var context = new MongoContext();
  var processes = new List<Task<UpdateResult>>();
  var collection = context.Storage.GetCollection<Option>("options");

  contracts.ForEach(contract =>
  {
    var item = Builders<Option>.Update.Set(o => o, contract);
    var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

    processes.Add(collection.UpdateOneAsync(o => o.Id == contract.Id, item, options));
  });

  return Task.WhenAll(processes);
}
```

Call for the method above

```
Task.WhenAll(service.SaveOptions(contracts)) // also tried without Task.WhenAll
```

**For some reason, it doesn't create any record in Mongo DB**

Update

Tried to rewrite bulk write this way, still no changes.

```
public Task SaveOptions(List<Option> contracts)
{
  var context = new MongoContext();
  var records = new List<UpdateOneModel<Option>>();
  var collection = context.Storage.GetCollection<Option>("options");

  contracts.ForEach(contract =>
  {
    var record = new UpdateOneModel<Option>(
      Builders<Option>.Filter.Where(o => o.Id == contract.Id),
      Builders<Option>.Update.Set(o => o, contract))
    {
      IsUpsert = true
    };

    records.Add(record);
  });

  return collection.BulkWriteAsync(records);
}
```

Comment: Hint: You don't want `UpdateOne`, you want `ReplaceOne` :)

Comment: @john it works, add this as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: even though, I thought that update and replace do the same thing, but update is more flexible because it allows to change structure of the record on update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `ReplaceOneAsync`:

```
processes.Add(collection.ReplaceOneAsync(o => o.Id == contract.Id, contract, options));
```

The problem with using `UpdateOneAsync` here is that you're supposed to specify a *field* to update, and `o => o` doesn't do that. Since you want to replace the entire object, you need to use `ReplaceOneAsync`.

** Note that you can also do this with `BulkWriteAsync` by creating a `ReplaceOneModel` instead of an `UpdateOneModel`.